# How to create jar for src/test and src/main using gradle 8.2?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I want to create dependancy for base project with src/main and src/test  in the azure devops artifacts so that all other project use structure within that project. How to create artifact using gradle 8.2 and use it in the other projects ?

I have tried below steps but its not working . I cant see any depedancy added in the based project to another project. Any help highly appreciated. Thanks

Step 1: Create the Base Project

Set up base project:
Create a new directory for base project and set up the standard Gradle project structure with src/main/java and src/test/java directories.

**Apply the Java plugin:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

Create a custom task for building the combined JAR:

```
task customJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.output
    from sourceSets.test.output
    archiveClassifier.set('all-in-one')
    version = '1.0' // Replace with your desired version
}
```

Configure the publishing to Azure DevOps Artifacts:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.example.base' // Replace with your desired group ID for the base project
            artifactId = 'base-library' // Replace with your desired artifact ID for the base project
            version = customJar.version
            artifact customJar
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "AzureDevOpsArtifacts"
            url = uri("https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/your-organization/_packaging/your-feed/maven/v1") // Replace with your Azure DevOps Artifacts feed URL
            credentials {
                username = project.findProperty("azureArtifactsUsername") ?: System.getenv("AZURE_ARTIFACTS_USERNAME")
                password = project.findProperty("azureArtifactsPassword") ?: System.getenv("AZURE_ARTIFACTS_PASSWORD")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Publish the base project artifact:
./gradlew publish

Step 2: Use the Base Project as a Dependency in Other Projects

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.example.base:base-library:1.0' // Replace with the appropriate version of the base project
}
```

Build your other projects to resolve the dependency from Azure DevOps Artifacts:

```
./gradlew build
```